# Retrieving individual pixel height data given color table/relief data and color shaded relief map using C# and GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, c#, colormap, colortable

I am using C# GDAL/OGR/OSR bindings. I have a GeoTIFF file where each pixel is stored as a color in a Red, Green, and Blue raster band. I have a color table/color relief file (.csv) which I am able to import using OGR's CSV driver. This file stores a starting elevation, red, green, and blue value per line. The first line begins at -9000 meters and the last line ends at 21000 meters.

I know there is a command using gdaldem to use a color relief file in order to create a color shaded version of a DEM, but is the reverse possible? If it is, how  can you do this using the GDAL/OGR/OSR C# API? The reason it is necessary is that I need to convert each pixel's color value to a normalized value between 0 and 1. 0 represents the minimum elevation and 1 represents the maximum. Therefore, it is not strictly necessary to convert the color pixel to a raw elevation (in meters). The color can be normalized directly if possible.

It seems like the way to go about it would be to find the two elevations a color falls between and then use a reverse linear interpolation algorithm to determine the normalized point of the color between the two elevations, however right now  I can't figure out how that is possible. I think a color could fall within multiple ranges.

So, is this possible, or impossible as I imagine?